# Count the number of Substrings occurences on a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with an ID and a nvarchar field.

In each line I have something like this:

```
ID   ClientID    TEXT
6       1          'Log Entry A' - 26/05/2014 17:32:30; - UserName 'Log Entry B' - 27/05/2014 18:30:30; - UserName
7       2          'Log Entry 2A' - 27/05/2014 17:32:30; - UserName 'Log Entry 2B' - 27/05/2014 18:32:30; - UserName
```

The TEXT field here is a NVARCHAR column that holds all the Client-related user activity on a given day (e.g.: all the user activity from the user UserName on the day 27/05/2014)

The problem is: I need to figure out how many times the user "UserName" had an activity logged on on each line.

Until now, I figured that using something like this:

```
(...) WHERE TEXT LIKE '%27/05/2014_____________UserName%'
```

I can ignore the hour and grab all the columns that have the date I want. However, this don't solve my problem: this just give if the user was logged on or not, but I still need to know how many times the user was logged on that day.

What I wanted from this is something similar to this:

```
SELECT ID, CountSubstrings(TEXT, '%27/05/2014_____________UserName%') as Count, TEXT
FROM ClientData WHERE TEXT LIKE '%27/05/2014_____________UserName%'
```

Which would give me this as a result:

```
ID    Count   TEXT
 6    1   'Log Entry A' - 26/05/2014 17:32:30; - UserName 'Log Entry B' - 27/05/2014 18:30:30; - UserName
 7    2   'Log Entry 2A' - 27/05/2014 17:32:30; - UserName 'Log Entry 2B' - 27/05/2014 18:32:30; - UserName
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, assuming the username is surrounded by spaces:

```
select t.*,
       ((len(' ' + text + ' ') -
         len(replace(' ' + text + ' ', ' ' + @UserName + ' ', ''))
        ) / (2 + len(@UserName)) -- the "2" is for the spaces at the beginning and end
       ) as NumberOfTimes 
from table t;
```

Comment: Hmm... No, this is not really what I need. I need to know the number of times a user went on activity on a given day. If a Line holds 3 user activities, but only two on the "filter-day", then "NumberOfTimes" should return 2, not 3. This will return 3.

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc361/3)**

```
DECLARE @SearchFilter nvarchar(max) = '%27/05/2014%'

SELECT
  [ClientID],
  COUNT(*) [count]
FROM ClientData t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<a>'+REPLACE([TEXT],';','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS xml)) t2(xml)
CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('a') t3(log_entry)
WHERE log_entry.value('.','nvarchar(max)') LIKE @SearchFilter
GROUP BY ClientID
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works? I'm not familiar with the XML functions.

Comment: Look at the output of `SELECT <a>'+REPLACE([TEXT],';','</a><a>')+'</a>' FROM ClientData`

Comment: @Anon Well. I put this on my server and tried to run. It is giving me a message saying that "log_entry can't be used directly".

Comment: @ThalesPereira use explicit column names instead of `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

A clean way would be to code an [SQL scalar-valued user defined function](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions) that returns the count of the substring you want to find in the provided string (a function that takes 2 parameters and does the count).

Comment: Tried that. I wasn't able to do a user-defined function that works right with Wildcards...